# What's the difference between ConstraintLayout and PercentRelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have used PercentRelativeLayout in a project but I would like to migrate it to new ConstraintLayout. Could someone please tell me the differences?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I have used PercentRelativeLayout in a project but I would like to
>   migrate it to new ConstraintLayout.

`PercentRelativeLayout` is built on top of RelativeLayout while `ConstraintLayout` is completely a different design layout which is not built on top of `RelativeLayout`

Also, Its still a very early days as `ConstraintLayout` is still in Alpha. So, I would recommend to wait for a while till proper documentation is available.